# how i can use my js class in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, import, export

i create my class

```
export default class Quiz{
    constructor() {
        this.quizWrapper = null;
        this.quizStage = null;
        this.progressed = 1;
        this.quizType = 'empty';
        this.scope = 0;
    }
    start(){
        this.scope= 1;
        return true;
    }
};
```

and import it with

```
// let test = new Quiz();
// console.log(test); // --> reurn the class fine 

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var test = new Quiz();
    console.log(test.start()); // --> reurn true
});
```

so is all fine but if i call *test* in console of browser i see error *Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined*

if I do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.test = new Quiz();
```

I can use it with `$.test` in console of browser.

Can someone please explain to me why that is? I would like to initialize my module after loading the scripts from jQuery and use it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are defining `test` inside a function, so it is not attached to global scope